Flutter: Drag and Drop Columns from Column Chooser to PlutoGrid
I'm working on a Flutter project where I need to implement a drag-and-drop functionality. I want to drag columns from an overlay column chooser and drop them into a specific position (index) in a PlutoGrid.
Specific Questions:
How can I enable drag-and-drop functionality from the overlay chooser to the PlutoGrid?
How can I determine and set the specific index in PlutoGrid where the column should be dropped?
Are there any best practices or libraries in Flutter that can help with this drag-and-drop functionality?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pluto_grid/pluto_grid.dart';
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';

List<Map<String, dynamic>> generateFakeData(int count) {
  final faker = Faker();
  return List.generate(count, (index) {
    return {
      'id': index + 1,
      'name': faker.person.name(),
      'email': faker.internet.email(),
      'phone': faker.phoneNumber.us(),
      'work': faker.address.state(),
      'fix': faker.date.justTime(),
      'company': faker.company.name(),
    };
  });
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'PlutoGrid with Column Chooser',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('PlutoGrid with Column Chooser')),
        body: const PlutoGridExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlutoGridExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlutoGridExample({super.key});

  @override
  _PlutoGridExampleState createState() => _PlutoGridExampleState();
}

class _PlutoGridExampleState extends State<PlutoGridExample> {
  late List<PlutoColumn> allColumns;
  late List<PlutoColumn> visibleColumns;
  late List<bool> columnVisibility;
  late List<PlutoRow> rows;
  bool showColumnChooser = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    allColumns = [
      PlutoColumn(
        title: 'ID',
        field: 'id',
        type: PlutoColumnType.number(),
      ),
      PlutoColumn(
        title: 'Name',
        field: 'name',
        type: PlutoColumnType.text(),
      ),
      PlutoColumn(
        title: 'Email',
        field: 'email',
        type: PlutoColumnType.text(),
      ),
      PlutoColumn(
        title: 'Phone',
        field: 'phone',
        type: PlutoColumnType.text(),
      ),
      PlutoColumn(
        title: 'State',
        field: 'work',
        type: PlutoColumnType.text(),
        hide: true,
      ),
      PlutoColumn(
        title: 'Phone Work',
        field: 'fix',
        type: PlutoColumnType.text(),
        hide: true,
      ),
      PlutoColumn(
        title: 'Company',
        field: 'company',
        type: PlutoColumnType.text(),
        hide: true,
      ),
    ];

    columnVisibility = List.filled(allColumns.length, true);
    visibleColumns = List.from(allColumns.where((column) => !column.hide));

    rows = generateFakeData(100).map((data) {
      return PlutoRow(cells: {
        'id': PlutoCell(value: data['id']),
        'name': PlutoCell(value: data['name']),
        'email': PlutoCell(value: data['email']),
        'phone': PlutoCell(value: data['phone']),
        'work': PlutoCell(value: data['work']),
        'fix': PlutoCell(value: data['fix']),
        'company': PlutoCell(value: data['company']),
      });
    }).toList();
  }

  void _toggleColumnChooser() {
    setState(() {
      showColumnChooser = !showColumnChooser;
    });
  }

  void _updateColumns(List<PlutoColumn> columns, List<bool> visibility) {
    setState(() {
      allColumns = List<PlutoColumn>.from(columns);
      columnVisibility = List<bool>.from(visibility);
      visibleColumns = [
        for (int i = 0; i < allColumns.length; i++)
          if (columnVisibility[i]) allColumns[i]
      ];
    });
  }

  void _onColumnDropped(PlutoColumn column, int dropIndex) {
    setState(() {
      if (!visibleColumns.contains(column)) {
        visibleColumns.insert(dropIndex, column);
        int columnIndex = allColumns.indexOf(column);
        columnVisibility[columnIndex] = true;
      }
    });
  }

  int _calculateDropIndex(double dropY) {
    double gridTop = 100.0; // Top position of the grid
    double rowHeight = 50.0; // Height of a single row
    return ((dropY - gridTop) / rowHeight).floor();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _toggleColumnChooser,
              child: Text('Choose Columns'),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: DragTarget<PlutoColumn>(
                onAcceptWithDetails: (details) {
                  int dropIndex = _calculateDropIndex(details.offset.dy);
                  _onColumnDropped(details.data, dropIndex);
                },
                builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
                  return PlutoGrid(
                    columns: visibleColumns,
                    rows: rows,
                    configuration: PlutoGridConfiguration(),
                    onChanged: (PlutoGridOnChangedEvent event) {
                      print(event);
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        if (showColumnChooser)
          Positioned(
            right: 0,
            top: 50,
            child: ColumnChooserOverlay(
              columns: allColumns,
              columnVisibility: columnVisibility,
              onColumnsChanged: _updateColumns,
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ColumnChooserOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<PlutoColumn> columns;
  final List<bool> columnVisibility;
  final Function(List<PlutoColumn>, List<bool>) onColumnsChanged;

  const ColumnChooserOverlay({
    super.key,
    required this.columns,
    required this.columnVisibility,
    required this.onColumnsChanged,
  });

  @override
  _ColumnChooserOverlayState createState() => _ColumnChooserOverlayState();
}

class _ColumnChooserOverlayState extends State<ColumnChooserOverlay> {
  late List<bool> _columnVisibility;
  late List<PlutoColumn> _columns;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _columnVisibility = List.from(widget.columnVisibility);
    _columns = List.from(widget.columns.where((column) => column.hide));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 8,
      child: Container(
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: ReorderableListView(
          onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
            setState(() {
              if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
                newIndex -= 1;
              }
              final item = _columns.removeAt(oldIndex);
              _columns.insert(newIndex, item);
              final visibilityItem = _columnVisibility.removeAt(oldIndex);
              _columnVisibility.insert(newIndex, visibilityItem);
              widget.onColumnsChanged(_columns, _columnVisibility);
            });
          },
          children: List.generate(_columns.length, (index) {
            return LongPressDraggable<PlutoColumn>(
              key: ValueKey(_columns[index].field), // Ensure each item has a key
              data: _columns[index],
              feedback: Material(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(_columns[index].title),
                ),
              ),
              childWhenDragging: Container(),
              child: CheckboxListTile(
                key: ValueKey(_columns[index].field), // Ensure each item has a key
                title: Text(_columns[index].title),
                value: _columnVisibility[index],
                onChanged: (bool? value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _columnVisibility[index] = value ?? true;
                    widget.onColumnsChanged(_columns, _columnVisibility);
                  });
                },
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

